# error in downloading RTMP video

Tags: video, download, rtmp

I want to download video from http://helper.ipam.ucla.edu/wowzavid...p4&vfd=DFT2016

I can watch this whole video through the web browser (chrome or IE), but the speed is too slow. So I want to download it. I tried with rtmpdump, it works at the beginning, as you see in the figure:

[image]

But after a while, it stops at about 70MB. I have tried several times, it all ended up like this.

[image]

Comment: can you give the link of the rest of image? I will try to display it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about `rtmpdump` but using `ffmpeg` it works like a charm.

Download and extract [`ffmpeg` static build](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Inside a bin directory you will find `ffmpeg` executable.

To download your stream run:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://128.97.46.13/DFT2016/mp4:13598.mp4 -c copy 13598.mp4
```